# Can you take more than one 5-foot-step using Combat reflexes, Evasive Reflexes and Robilar's Gambit together, or Shifting Defence by itself?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, movement, tome-of-battle

Can you using these three feats, take more then one five foot step per round?

From Robilar's Gambit:

> In return, they provoke attacks of opportunity from you each time they swing

From Evasive reflexes:

> When an opponent gives you a chance to make an attack of opportunity, you can instead immediately take a 5-foot step.

In RAW you can only make one 5-foot step per turn, this does not specifically state that you can take more but this suggests that you can.

If this combination doesn't, would the stance Shifting Defense from setting sun work?

> While you are in this stance, you can make an immediate 5-foot step each time an opponent attacks you. Moving in this manner consumes one of your attacks of opportunity in the current round

Answer (score 3):

Both Evasive Reflexes and *shifting defense* allow you to take a 5-foot step, period. They let you do that even though it isn’t your turn and you couldn’t otherwise take one. They are each an exception to all kinds of rules around 5-foot steps. Normally you can only make one a turn, but these specifically allow you to take a 5-foot step when you normally couldn’t. So yes, they allow you to take more than one 5-foot step per turn.

Technically, it would prevent you from using your *regular* 5-foot step on your turn, if you somehow got someone to provoke you during your turn and used Evasive Reflexes or *shifting defense* without having previously used a 5-foot step. But if you had already used your regular 5-foot step, you’d get a second. And when you use Evasive Reflexes or *shifting defense* out of turn (as you do 99% of the time), you get a 5-foot step (regardless of any you have previously used during your turn or from previous triggers of Evasive Reflexes or *shifting defense*), and your ability to use a 5-foot step refreshes on your own turn. So this would rarely come up, and a DM should probably just ignore it and say that the Evasive Reflexes 5-foot step doesn’t count against using a regular 5-foot step.

Comment: There was a Sage answer which suggested evasive reflexes took up your attacks of opportunity (so normally you would only get 1 provoked step/round). I don't see that reflected in the text though.

Comment: @fectin The Sage should by-and-large be ignored. Evasive Reflexes does not use an attack of opportunity—in fact it is explicitly triggered by *not* using one.

Answer (score 2):

## Some feats assume a creature can take multiple 5-ft. steps even when the feat doesn't allow the creature to

A creature really *can't* take more than one [5-ft. step](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101210738/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_5footstep&alpha=) in a round unless a special ability explicitly allows it. The *Player’s Handbook* on [Take 5-Foot Step](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/actionsInCombat.html#5-ft-step) says

> **You can move 5 feet *in any round* when you don’t perform *any* other kind of movement.** Taking this 5-foot step never provokes an attack of opportunity. You can't take more than one 5-foot step in a round, and you can't take a 5-foot step in the same round when you move any distance.
>
> You can take a 5-foot step before, during, or after your other actions in the round…. (144)

(Emphasis and *double* emphasis mine.) That's in a *round*, not just during the creature's turn. Since a creature's relative round begins at the beginning of its turn this absolute round and ends on the same initiative count on the *next* absolute round, a typical creature that *either* takes a 5-ft. step *or* moves at least 10 ft. on its turn *really is* prohibited from taking *another* 5-ft. step during its round unless it's explicitly allowed to do. (Also, to be clear, as a creature's usually finished its actions on its turn, a creature can't usually take a 5-ft. step off-turn.)

Authors frequently omit this explicit exception. You've already listed the Setting Sun maneuver shifting defense [stance] (*ToB* 73) and the feat Evasive Reflexes (*ToB* 30) but similarly affected are feats like Cunning Evasion (*PH2* 78), Net and Trident (*CW* 114), Opportunistic Tactician (*Dragon* #340 87), and Orien Battle Stride (*Dra* 143). (Note that there's no consistency here—it's not like a lone author or editor is responsible for all this confusion; instead it's a general malaise that hovers on the game's edges, awaiting discovery and sending those who do into fits of seething anger. Also note that I may be projecting.)

This means that—despite, for example, the benefit of Evasive Reflexes or the description of shifting defense *strongly* implying otherwise—, the rules do, in fact, *still* prevent creatures employing such effects from taking multiple 5-ft. steps in a round unless those creatures have *another* special ability explicitly *allowing* multiple 5-ft. steps. Obviously…

### This is terrible!

…And it's made even worse because sometimes a feat *will* follow the rules. For example, the feats Psionic Sidestep (Expanding Your Mind Web column ["New Psychic Warrior Feats, Powers, and Ranged Weapon Enhancements"](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031215600/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/pse/20030426a)) *et al.*, Pursue (*ECS* 58), and Sidestep (*MH* 28) recognize, accommodate, or work around the 5-ft. step rule, making it look like those *other* feats *should* be limited when, in all likelihood—especially given the rarity of *other* special abilities that *allow* a creature to take more than one 5-ft. step in a round—those feats *shouldn't* be so limited.

#### Urge the DM to institute a house rule!

This DM strongly urges a house rule saying that any feat that seemingly intends to allow multiple 5-ft. steps in a round (like those listed above) instead allows the creature to move up to 5 ft. without provoking attacks of opportunity; this is not an action. Such a house rule *both* avoids conflicts with *actually* taking a 5-ft. step *and* soothes the seething anger of folks who think too much about this stuff.

---

## About that *Tome of Battle* Q & A

[Fectin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/25662/fectin) mentioned in a comment on KRyan's fine [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84043/8610) an answer from the Sage that addresses the feat Evasive Reflexes. Edited for readability but not content, here's that exchange:

> **Questions:** The *Tome of Battle* includes a feat named Evasive Reflexes. This feat is raising a lot of questions on the message boards. Here are the main questions that I hope you can shed some light on:
>
> 1. If I have both Evasive Reflexes and Combat Reflexes, and I am normally entitled to four attacks of opportunity per round, what is the maximum number of 5-foot-steps per round that I can make using Evasive Reflexes?
> 2. Do the 5-foot-step(s) that I make using Evasive Reflexes count against the total number of attacks of opportunity that I can make in a single round?
>
> Thanks in advance.
>
> **Answers:**
>
> 1. Four. You can take a five foot step each time an enemy provokes.
> 2. Yes they do! Essentially you are replacing the attack with the move, but it still uses up an attack of opportunity!

This comes from a thread of compiled *Tome of Battle* wisdom purportedly from the Sage that's archived on various sites around the Web. (Most accessible is likely this [Oct. 2015 thread](https://www.enworld.org/threads/tome-of-battle-q-a-magocrat.471387/) on *EN World*, but there's also a [Mar. 2015 archive](https://www.goddessfantasy.net/bbs/?topic=74889.0) and [an undated one](http://drammelsnotes.wikidot.com/the-unofficial-official-errata) on different Web sites.) That *purportedly* isn't intended cast any doubt on anyone's honesty; instead, the questions and answers—while in the style of later [Ask Wizards](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101182701/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/askwiz) and [Sage Advice Online](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101182657/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/asksage) columns—appear to be just a collection of largely unsourced Customer Service email responses, which were, in the day, notoriously unreliable and contradictory.

This answer is not immune. The benefit of the feat Evasive Reflexes says

> When an opponent gives you a chance to make an attack of opportunity, you can instead immediately take a 5-foot step. (*ToB* 30)

Seriously. That's the whole thing. So rather than make an attack of opportunity, a creature opts to take a 5-ft. step. The benefit of Evasive Reflexes does *not* say the creature *spends* an attack of opportunity to make that 5-ft. step. In fact, considering the benefit's weird *gives you a chance* language, an argument can be made that even a creature that's exhausted *all* its attacks of opportunity can take the 5-ft. step granted by the feat's benefit!

So while the answer could, were it properly sourced, relay designer intent, the answer doesn't address what the text *says*, and the answer isn't official errata (also see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq)). The answer *could* make for a relatively reasonable house rule… at least until the player of a feat-starved scout starts eyeing Evasive Reflexes so his character can skirmish better without the burden of Combat Reflexes. Then such a player should try to persuade the DM to reconsider the sage's ruling.

On the stance shifting defense, the same thread includes this exchange:

> **Question:** Does the shifting defense stance grant you a 5-foot step before the attack roll is made, making it miss because of your movement, or after the attack roll is made and consequently results in a failure?
> **Answer:** The shifting defense maneuver grants you a 5-foot step after you know that the attack misses, because the stance states that it is activated upon a failed attack.

That's because the description of shifting defense says

> *You duck and move as you dodge your opponent’s attacks. Slowly but surely, each attack gives you the opportunity to move across the battlefield.*
>
> Your ability to read your opponents' moves and use their strength against them allows you to shift your position during a battle. Each **failed** attack gives you the split-second you need to move without drawing attacks.
>
> While you are in this stance, you can make an immediate 5-foot step each time an opponent attacks you. Moving in this manner consumes one of your attacks of opportunity in the currrent round. You cannot move in this manner if you have no attacks of opportunity remaining. This movement does not provoke attacks of opportunity. (*ToB* 73)

Emphasis mine. So that Q & A *is* rules-accurate, but, seriously, saying *failed* in the second paragraph but not in the first and third? I don't even. Anyway, a defender using shifting defense in conjunction with the feat Robilar's Gambit (*PH2* 82) means the attacker provokes 1 attack of opportunity for making an attack and, if the attack misses, the defender can opt to spend 1 more attack of opportunity to take a 5-ft. step (or, if you prefer—I know *I* do—*move up to 5 ft. without provoking attacks of opportunity; this is not an action*.)

Comment: I see nothing in the 5-foot step rules demanding extra-special explicit exemption; why would the statement that you can take one not be good enough to override all reasons you otherwise couldn’t? *Tome of Battle* doesn’t explicitly say you can 5-foot step out of turn, either; are you saying these features are limited to your turn, as well?

Comment: Not having moved prior is a requirement to use a 5-foot step, which is therefore ignored when something says you can use one. At that point, you are already past the requirements and don’t check them. I have no idea what you even mean by “that's how movement—not the 5-ft. step—works,” much less where that idea is coming from.

Comment: @KRyan I'm sorry I was unclear. You're right—not having moved *is* a requirement to use a 5-ft. step, but the listed feats don't remove that requirement.  They say you can take a 5-ft. step. That *can* be done *without* lifting the requirement by opting not to move during one's turn. The feat *must* lift the requirement explicitly because the limit is *already* one.

Comment: Why? It’s an exception-based ruleset, these are clearly more specific, these features are already making implicit exemptions to other requirements, why is *this one requirement* special and requiring an explicit exemption?

Comment: @KRyan But both of our exceptions are valid. I think I understand our disconnect. I lack the math expressions to put it the right way, so prepare to cringe, but it's the difference between [A can 5-ft. step if X happens] and [A can 5-ft. step]+[if X happens]. If the *whole thing* is the how we're to read it, then the feats work, but if the rules *are* merely making a *very* specific exception to when 5-ft. steps can be taken, then they don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42426/discussion-between-kryan-and-hey-i-can-chan).